# URL Rewriting - htaccess web.config

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, web-config

I have imported in IIS these rewrite rules :

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)/([0-9]+)?$ search.html?name=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)?$ search.html?name=$1&page=1 [QSA,L]
```

Translation is :

```
match url="^search/(.+)/([0-9]+)?$" ignoreCase="false"
action type="Rewrite" url="search.html?name={R:1}&amp;page={R:2}" appendQueryString="true"

match url="^search/(.+)?$" ignoreCase="false"
action type="Rewrite" url="search.html?name={R:1}&amp;page=1" appendQueryString="true"
```

but when i'm testing doesn't work

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found -this is the error

Answer (score 0):

Try with a condition,

conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false"

(did not include opening and closing tags.)